# Trying to have drag-n-drop behaviour from a python side generated list

Tags: python, kivy

( learner alert )

as part of my learn by doing first project im trying to build an organiser of sorts.

[image: example_pic]

as you will see from the code the jobs column is populated and i can drag them to the user columns , stack and reorder them, all good

however in the experimental column im trying to have a template ( a boxlayout with a label, text input and buttons ) that is generated on the python side as down the line i want to feed the entries from a database.

ive gotten to the point where i can loop a builder.string as an f"" ( hence the numbering ) and they have draggable behaviour but i cant drop them into the user columns like i can with the ones from the jobs column and this is where im stuck lol

ive tried to build it up in sequence on the python side but started to run into errors and code was getting messy by then lol so ive rewound to this point.

tldr -

how can i get the entries in the experimental column to drag and drop into the user columns as they do from the jobs column.  thanks! lol

code -

currently its all in the .py, no .kv

#.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
import kivy_garden.draggable
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy_garden.draggable import KXReorderableBehavior

KV_CODE = '''
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label
<DraggableItem@KXDraggableBehavior+BoxLayout>:
    entrylabel: entrylabeli
    
    orientation: 'vertical'
    drag_cls: 'test'
    opacity: .7 if self.is_being_dragged else 1.
    size_hint:1,None
    height:75
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1 if root.is_being_dragged else 0
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: [*self.pos, *self.size, ]
    Label:
        id:entrylabeli
        text: 'hellos'
        size_hint:1,None
        height:35
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint:1,None
        height:35
        Button:
            text: 'button01'
            size_hint:1,None
            height:35
        Button:
            text: 'button01'
            size_hint:1,None
            height:35
            
<ReorderableBoxLayout@KXReorderableBehavior+KXDroppableBehavior+BoxLayout>:

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint:1,None
        height:35
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:0,1,0,0.55
            Rectangle:
                size:self.size
                pos:self.pos
        
        Label:
            text: 'experimental'
        Label:
            text: 'jobs'
        Label:
            text: 'user01'
        Label:
            text: 'user02'
        Label:
            text: 'user03'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'        
        
        # experimental code column
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            ReorderableBoxLayout:
                id: boxlayoutexp
                drag_classes: ['test', ]
                spacer_widgets:
                    [
                    Label(text='3rd spacer', font_size=40, size_hint_min_y='50sp'),
                    Label(text='2nd spacer', font_size=40, size_hint_min_y='50sp'),
                    Label(text='1st spacer', font_size=40, size_hint_min_y='50sp'),
                    ]
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: 10
                spacing:7
                size_hint_min_y: self.minimum_height
        
        # example code column
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            ReorderableBoxLayout:
                id: boxlayout
                drag_classes: ['test', ]
                spacer_widgets:
                    [
                    Label(text='3rd spacer', font_size=40, size_hint_min_y='50sp'),
                    Label(text='2nd spacer', font_size=40, size_hint_min_y='50sp'),
                    Label(text='1st spacer', font_size=40, size_hint_min_y='50sp'),
                    ]
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: 10
                size_hint_min_y: self.minimum_height   
        
        # columns for jobs to be arranged in
        ReorderableBoxLayout:
            drag_classes: ['test', ]
            padding: 10
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7
                Rectangle:
                    size:self.size
                    pos:self.pos
        
        # columns for jobs to be arranged in
        ReorderableBoxLayout:
            drag_classes: ['test', ]
            padding: 10
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:0.5,0.5,0.5,0.4
                Rectangle:
                    size:self.size
                    pos:self.pos
                    
        # columns for jobs to be arranged in
        ReorderableBoxLayout:
            drag_classes: ['test', ]
            padding: 10
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:0.5,0.5,0.5,0.2
                Rectangle:
                    size:self.size
                    pos:self.pos
'''


class DraggableItem():
    pass

class entry_container():

    def build_entries(self,):

        for i in range(1,10+1):

            dylbl = f"""
            
<MyLay@KXDraggableBehavior+KXReorderableBehavior+BoxLayout>:

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint:1,None
    height:100
    MyLay:
        orientation: "vertical"
        #drag_classes: ['test', ]
        Label:
            text: " here's me label {i} :) "
        TextInput:
            hint_text: " notes go here "
        Button:
            text: " and here's me btn :) "
        
"""
            self.root.ids.boxlayoutexp.add_widget(Builder.load_string(dylbl))

class entry_template(KXReorderableBehavior,BoxLayout):
    pass


class sclbx():
    pass


class MyboxlayApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(KV_CODE)

    def on_start(self):
        entry_container.build_entries(self,)
        DraggableItem = Factory.DraggableItem
        add_widget = self.root.ids.boxlayout.add_widget
        for i in range(1, 20 + 1):
            add_widget(DraggableItem())  # text=str(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyboxlayApp().run()
```

## EDIT

yes! Mr Anderson once i setup -

```
Mylay:
    drag_classes: ["test", ]
    drag_cls: "test"
```

it started working across all columns :D
to be honest ive put those in all the targeted boxes for now just to test lol

seems a bit janky or stuttery but i noticed its to do with the reorder behaviour, but i intend to seperate and rewrite it so im sure ill be able to smooth out the kinks :)

Thanks again!!

Comment: I think you need to handle `drag_classes` and `drag_cls` for the `MyLay` class.